# Mongo DB sorting exception - too much data for sort() with no index

Tags: mongodb, exception, sorting, indexing

Using ***MongoDB version 2.4.4***, I have a profile collection containing profiles documents. 
I have the following query:

```
Query: { "loc" : { "$near" : [ 32.08290052711715 , 34.80888522811172] , "$maxDistance" : 0.0089992800575954}} 
Fields: { "friendsCount" : 1 , "tappsCount" : 1 , "imageUrl" : 1 , "likesCount" : 1 , "lastActiveTime" : 1 , "smallImageUrl" : 1 , "loc" : 1 , "pid" : 1 , "firstName" : 1} 
Sort: { "lastActiveTime" : -1}
```

Limited to 100 documents.

***loc*** - embedded document containing the keys ( lat,lon)

***I am getting the exception:***

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or specify a smaller limit;

As stated in the exception when I down-size the limit to 50 it works.. but it ain't option for me.
I have the following 2 relevant indexes on the profile document:

```
{'loc':'2d'}
{'lastActiveTime':-1}
```

I have also tried compound index as below but without success.

```
{'loc':'2d', 'lastActiveTime':-1}
```

This is example document (with the relevant keys):

```
{
  "_id" : "5d5085601208aa918bea3c1ede31374d",
  "gender" : "female",
  "isCreated" : true,
  "lastActiveTime" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:30:56.615Z"),
  "loc" : {
    "lat" : 32.082230499955806,
    "lon" : 34.813542940344945,
    "locTime" : NumberLong(0)
  }
}
```

There are other fields in the profile documents .. basically average profile document size is 0.5 MB
 correct me if I am wrong but if I am specifying only the relevant response fields (as I do)
 it is not the cause for the problem.

Don't know if it helps but when I down-size the limit size to 50 and the query succeed
I have the following explain information (via MongoVUE client)

```
 cursor : GeoSearchCursor
 isMultyKey : False
 n : 50
 nscannedObjects : 50
 nscanned : 50
 nscannedObjectsAllPlans : 50
 nscannedAllPlans : 50
 scanAndOrder : True
 indexOnly : False
 nYields : 0
 nChunkSkips : 0
 millis : 10
 indexBounds :
```

It is a blocker for me and I will appreciate your help, what am I doing wrong? How can I make the query roll with the needed limit size?

Comment: How long does it take to get the 50 documents?

Comment: You can see in the explain it says 10 millisecond , very fast.

Comment: Oh, in the image. Can you get rid of all that whitespace in the image by chance? The relevant portion shows up as 30px or so in SO. Better yet, just copy the data to the question. Also, 10 millis isn't very fast for a high-performance site, that's only 100 requests a second, but maybe that's acceptable for you.

Comment: there you go edited the question

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I don't know the answer, but hopefully this makes the problem more obvious to someone more familiar with Mongo than I.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a compound index instead of two indexes.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { 'loc':'2d','lastActiveTime':-1 } )
```

You can also suggest the query which index to use:

```
db.collection.find(...).hint('myIndexName')
```

Comment: already tried the compound index ... as I mentioned in my question. which index to suggest in the hint? I need to indexes to operate the query can I suggest both?

Comment: there is only one compound index to suggest.

Comment: tried that also creating compound index and suggesting it with hint... without success